# Doubts with metadata api

Tags: metadata-api

[image]

[image]

Hello, good afternoon everyone, I have this problem, I created an integration user with the "Salesforce Integration" license and I had this error of insufficient access, I looked for a way to create a set of permissions, but I can only assign this access to modify with api metadata if salesforce license.

---

[image]

[image]

Even after assigning this license to the integration user I still have the same error, do I need any more permissions?

Comment: In my experience, the free Integration licences were designed for data integrations. If you're looking to do high-privilege Metadata API actions, the behaviour seems less consistent. It seems to be that if you create a permission set with all the stuff you'd otherwise have on a profile, you don't get the same experience.

Comment: I managed to solve it by creating a permission set without a license, assigning permission to modify metadata

Answer (score 1):

More likely than not, you forgot to assign to the user a Permission Set License `Salesforce API Integration`[image]

The Permission Set License defines what kinds of permissions are possible to assign to the user

This enables assigning the permission: `Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions` to the user within a Permission Set.

[image]

However, other permissions will need to be granted to the user. This Gearset (a devops vendor) [article](https://gearset.com/blog/what-are-salesforce-integration-user-licenses/) goes through the considerations

Comment: I asked a new question, attached images